# DAX PowerBI: Calculating sum of column based on other column

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am trying to calculate the TotalFTE, but I can't figure it out. I am fairly new to DAX and trying to make the best of it with some studycases.

The table contains a lot of columns, but these are the columns that are needed for the measure.

The measure should  sum the highest FTE in a year per ID and ignore the blanks in ID.

I've build a measure that gives an error when I try to visulise the result in a card. My measure: TotalFTE = CALCULATE(MAX(Table[FTE]), FILTER(Table, DISTINCT(Table[ID])))

Any feedback?

[image: Example of the table -- Semi Result -- Result Measure]

[image: Error]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moving forward, please post data as tables in stack and refrain from provide the data as image.

```
Measure =
SUMX (
    GROUPBY (
        'Fact',
        'Fact'[year],
        'Fact'[ID],
        "@Max", MAXX ( CURRENTGROUP (), 'Fact'[FTE] )
    ),
    [@Max]
)
```